# Can nodes of Gaussian quadrature shift range?

Tags: mathematica

I used my Python program to generate Gaussian's nodes and their weights. My python program could generate nodes as default in rage of (-1, 1). And my friend used Mathematica to generate them also but with using by Mathematica he could generate nodes in range of (0, 2).

My question is how can i shift my nodes from range (-1, 1) to (0, 2)?

In my opinion i think just +1 to every elements of nodes that enough but one thing that i concern about it's how about their weights. Can i use the old one? Is there any affect to weights from my shifting nodes' range?